# Global search box bug - uncaught action failed - possibly Winter '23 release related

Tags: javascript

Since the Winter '23 release, the Global Search Box returns a 'Sorry to interrupt' error message now when 3 characters or more are input:

Uncaught Action failed: forceSearch:assistantSuggestionsDataProvider$controller$provide [Cannot read property 'setTimeout' of null]

This isn't reproducible in the UAT sandbox, the critical updates between UAT and Prod are the same and this issue is being thrown across different users with different permissions and on different Lightning apps.

This is happening across both Edge and Chrome and Chrome version is Version 80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: The browser versions being used are significantly out of date but something must have happened since Winter '23 which has resulted in this happening. I presume that a enforced update happened as per https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_ru.htm&type=5&release=240 which results in a regression when one is using an out of date browser but I haven't yet confirmed this.

Comment: I have just noticed that it was working fine in UAT because I am using Version 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit) for that but was using version 80 for Prod. So it certainly seems to be browser related but as to what exactly has caused this on the Salesforce side is yet to be determined. I don't see explicit versions as per https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&type=5.

Answer (score 1):

even my users are also facing same issue who are using chrome version 80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (32-bit).

So we updated to chrome to latest version and It's worked.

Let me know if there are any other ways we can do without updating chrome.

Thanks,
Ramana

Answer (score 1):

There's no known issue for it - but, this is due to using an old Chromium browser (less than v85).

A previous check for the older versions was removed - hence, the issue starting at some point recently.

As a user, you can update your browser to avoid this. Otherwise, I believe the evaluation (for older browser version) has been re-added to avoid this error for Spring 23 (*safe harbor*).